# Trying to show coordinates on picture And I can't understand why it's not working

Tags: python, opencv

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

#Drawing a circle
def circle(event, x, y, flags, param):
    if event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN:
        font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX
        string = str(x) + " " + str(y)
        cv2.putText(img, string, (x, y), font, 1, (255, 255, 0), 2)
        cv2.imshow('image', img)

#black screen
img = np.zeros((512, 512, 3), np.uint8)
cv2.imshow('image', img)
cv2.setMouseCallback('image ', circle)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please edit your code. And try to be more clear to explain your question. You may visit and check [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by changing in cv2.imshow('image',img) to cv2.imshow( "image ",img) 
Good luck everybody!